# How to redirect webServer to Chrome browser by trigger- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, hyperlink, webbrowser-control

I'm creating one product(webServer), That product provides wifi Hotpot. If you connect that Hotspot, webServer will open automatically on the default browser. In some Mobile, It opens on WEB UI browser(it's not installed browser). Our webServer works better in Google Chrome or any other mainstream browser, so if there is any possibility to redirect to Chrome browser by any trigger or else any possibility to open server only on Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to open a specific browser of a system. The reason is that you are requesting the system to handle a scheme (like http://, https://, ftp:// or file://) and the system will decide how to handle this . For http:// and https:// it's (most of the time) the browser defined by the user.

In addition, Chrome might not be available on every device requesting your server.